# Start two Junit test suites

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, test-suite

I have two junit test suites, First one will be AllTestInParallel and implemented it to run in multiple threads. Second one is AllTestsInSequence which is quite slower and I need to run in single thread. Finally I need to start both test suites at once. My intention is to run slow tests in first and then run fast test or vise versa.

```
  @RunWith(MultiThreadedClasspathRunner.class)
  public class AllTestsInParallel { 
  }

  public class MultiThreadedClasspathRunner extends Suite {
  public MultiThreadedClasspathRunner(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)    throws InitializationError {
    super(builder, MultiThreadedClasspathRunner.getTestClassesInProjectClassPath(klass));
  }
  ......
  }

  @RunWith(SingleThreadedClasspathRunner.class)
  public class AllTestsInSequence { 
  }

  public class SingleThreadedClasspathRunnerextends Suite {
  public SingleThreadedClasspathRunner(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)    throws InitializationError {
    super(builder, SingleThreadedClasspathRunner.getTestClassesInProjectClassPath(klass));
  }
  ......
  }
```

Can anyone let me know to initiate both runners at once? I tried using jvm param '-Dtest' as below;

```
     -Dtest=com.selenium.runner.AllTestsInSequence,com.selenium.runner.AllTestsInParallel
```

But it always get last value and execute. Is it possible to start one after other in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Suite`annotation to create a new suite containing both of the suites you want to run:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   AllTestsInParallel.class,
   AllTestsInSequence .class
})
public class AllTestsSuite {   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @JDC You saved my day.